# Is there any way to switch from Kepler to Indigo Ecplise?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Kepler; but some plugins are nt working properly with it so I want to use Eclipse;
any easy way to switch to Indigo?? except downloading complete Indigo package and reinstalling eclipse??

Comment: i am afraid not. but i agree with you 100% indigo is far more stable

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to downgrade from Kepler to Indigo. But as you mentioned, I found many issues related to plugins not working very well, I have reported them, so you can try to report the issues you find to help the developers improving this new release.

What you can do, to avoid installation is the following:

1. Get a copy of Eclipse Indigo (zip file if you are on Windows or tar if you are on Ubuntu)
2. Unzip the file to a new directory
3. Add the plugins you have installed to the plugins directory of Indigo.
4. Zip the Eclipse Indigo with the plugins you have in order to restore your IDE whenever you want.

I work with Indigo, I've been facing some issues with new releases of Eclipse, for me, Indigo is the most stable version and the less problematic (just an opinion, not a fact).

That's the solution I can propose, if somebody have a better idea, it would be nice to know how to handle this issue.

Good luck.

Best regards.

Comment: Reporting issues is a good idea.
Yes the one way you suggested is not bad but
I was just searching for a way to avoid downloading it again; simply a way to downgrade.
Anyways, Thanks.